# Where Visual Studio ASP project can keep files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

My ASP MVC project uses a CSS file. The CSS file is registered in BundleConfig.

When I edited style,I saw, that my edits are not visible on the site. I cleared CSS file, but the site is still displayed exactly the same.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Haha Silly question, but have you deployed your site after making your change?

Answer (score 0):

Yees, i'm really stupid. Browser saved css-style in cache. After Ctrl+F5 in browser - all editions became visible!